# Pointer based array access in MIPS

Tags: assembly, mips, cpu-architecture

What do we mean by the pointer based array access in MIPS?

Comment: Related: [Load Word in MIPS, using register instead of immediate offset from another register](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74769617) for indexed addressing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an additional possible meaning or implication to "pointer based array access":

You may have a pointer to an array, rather than an array at a fixed address. Actually, in C/C++, a "pointer to an array" is really usually just a pointer to the first element of the array. Basically, you have an array that is a parameter to a function, or a pointer to an array that is a member of a struct or class:

```
 void Foo(char a[]); 
   /*or*/ void Foo(char *a);
 struct Bar {  int offset4bytes; char* a; };
```

Typically, when you want to use such an array, the base address of the array will be loaded into a register.

Now say you want to access element i of such an array,

```
 char tmp = a[i];
```

Let's say that r1 contains the array address.  (Actually, probably a different register, specified by the calling convention, for the function paramaters.  Whatever the compiler finds available for other code.)

Let's say that i lives in register r2.

And, for good measure, let tmp be r3.

On some instruction sets, e.g. Intel x86, there is an addressing mode that looks like

```
  MOV r3, (r2,r1)4
```

i.e. the addressing mode can add two registers and an offset (I arbitrarily added a field to the struct example so that I could show this).

Heck, they can even scale one of the registers, the so-called index register:

```
  MOV r3, (r2*2,r1)4
```

or as I prefer to write it

```
  r3 := load( Memory[r2<<1+r1+4]
```

MIPS, however, does not have this sort of base+_index*scale+offset addressing mode. Most MIPS memory access instructions are limited to register+offset. Therefore, for MIPS, you might have to do

```
  ADDU r10, r1,r1    ; dest on left. r10 = 2*r1
  ADDU r11, r2,r10  
  LB r3,(r11)4
```

i.e. you might have to add extra RISC instructions to accomplish what x86 does in one CISC instruction with a complicated addressing mode.  However, such addressing is not common, and canm often be avoided.

---

Further, even just addressing an array at a fixed address may require extra instructions in MIPS.  x86 instructions can have a 32 bit memory offset - which in this case may actually be an absolute address of an array.  MIPS instructions are limited to a 16 bit offset - MIPS instructions are fixed width, 32 bits wide. Therefore, a separate instruction may be required even to access an array at a fixed address, typically to load the upper bits of the address into a register.

And more - MIPS has newer instructions like LUXC1, that have reg+reg addressing modes.  But not scaled index, and no third offset component.

---

Because of this restricted addressing modes, the code that a naive compiler generates for a lop such as

```
   for(int i=0;i<N;i++) {
      this->a[i] = 0;
   }
```

would be inefficient, if the loop contained the multiple instruction sequence mentioned above.

A loop such as

```
   for(char *p=this->a;p<&(this->a[N]);p++) {
      *p=0;
   }
```

or, equivalently

```
   for(char *p=this->a;p<this->a+N;p++) {
      *p;
   }
```

or  even sometimes

```
   for(i=-N,*p=this->a;i<0;i++,p++) {
      *p=0;
   }
```

might be more efficient, because, e.g. in the first two there would only be a single instruction to do the store. (The last is usually only a win if traversing several arrays.

Now, in a simple example any good compiler will do this optimization for you. But sometimes the compiler prefers such pointer based accesses.

Comment: Possibly relevant: from the file cflops.c in the Langer98 version of the Livermore Loops benchmark, http://www.aip.org/cip/langer.htm: 
   A C compiler, as of 1998, often produces faster code when accessing 
   global data than when accessing data through a pointer. A side effect 
   of using global structures is that the performance seen in this
   benchmark may be higher than that of many real world codes that use
   pointers heavily. A compiler flag declaring that there is no
   "pointer aliasing" in a program may get around this performance loss.

Answer (score 0):

You will have a pointer that points to the beginning of the array of values. To traverse the array you will use pointer arithmetic (usually adding/subtracting 1, 2, or 4) to advance the pointer to the next/previous element in the array.